# Crop an image displayed in a Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I have a canvas tag:

```
<canvas width="321" height="240" id="img_source"></canvas>
```

I want to add a crop functionality, so I made a resizeable div that can identify the borders of cropped image through dragging the corners of the div using the mouse. It looks like the image below:

[image]

[image]

I'm currently using "toDataURL()" to convert the data from the canvass to an image that can be displayed by an `<img>` tag. My question is, How will I convert to an image only part of the canvas that was identified by the resizeable div?

Comment: there is a great tutorial here: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/10/30/resizing-cropping-images-canvas/

Comment: and this tutorial www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-image-crop/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the method [getImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData) with the selected rectangle coordinates. For example:

```
let imageData = ctx.getImageData(65, 60, 100, 100);
```

Then create a secondary canvas with the desired sizes and use [putImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/putImageData) to set the pixels:

```
let canvas1 = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas1.width = 100;
canvas1.height = 100;
let ctx1 = canvas1.getContext("2d");
ctx1.rect(0, 0, 100, 100);
ctx1.fillStyle = 'white';
ctx1.fill();
ctx1.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
```

Finally use `toDataURL` to update the image:

```
dstImg.src = canvas1.toDataURL("image/png");
```

See the full sample I've prepared for you in [CodePen](http://codepen.io/rijii49/pen/Jopwmz?editors=101)

Comment: Good answer. One improvement, use the clipping version of `drawImage` to draw the clipped section of the original canvas onto canvas1. This avoids the slower `.getImageData` and `.putImageData` commands. Also, if the clipped image(s) are staying on the page (if the clipped images are not being saved to server or user's computer), you can just add your canvas1 to the DOM and it will visually display like an img element. This would be important if the original image source is cross-domain because then both `toDataURL` and `getImageData` would be prevented for security reasons.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I'm absolutely agree with you :) 
Of course using canvas as a DOM element would be better; I've just tried to stick with the question and not confuse PO with too much of additional information. For the same reason I said nothing about CORS because almost sure the image is from the same domain.

Comment: @AlexanderDayan -Thanks for giving me an idea. Anyways do you have any idea hot to get the parameters of getImageData dynamically? In my case, Im using a resizable div to determine the image borders. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AlyssaGono I'm not sure that I understand the last question. Could you please explain more how you want to use it and what result do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 9):

Create a new canvas at destination size, draw in the cropped image using drawImage() and insert that canvas into the DOM avoiding using img and data-uri:

```
var ccanvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
    cctx = ccanvas.getContext("2d");

ccanvas.width = w;
ccanvas.height = h;

// draw with crop arguments
cctx.drawImage(image_src,  x, y, w, h,  0, 0, w, h);
//                         ^^^^^^^^^^ source region
//                                      ^^^^^^^^^^ dest. region

// insert cropped image somewhere in the DOM tree:
document.body.appendChild(ccanvas);
```

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var img = document.getElementById("image_src");

  document.body.appendChild(region2canvas(img, 150, 60, 220, 200));
}

function region2canvas(img, x, y, w, h) {
  var ccanvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
    cctx = ccanvas.getContext("2d");

  ccanvas.width = w;
  ccanvas.height = h;

  // draw with crop arguments
  cctx.drawImage(img, x, y, w, h, 0, 0, w, h);

  return ccanvas;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/kWI4Cmz.png" id="image_src">
```

Answer (score 2):

The key to cropping from one image is that the context's drawImage method allows us to render a cropped section of the source image to the canvas.

```
context.drawImage(img, sx, sy, sw, sh, dx, dy, dw, dh);
```

**img** - *Source image object*
**sx** - *Source x*
**sy** - *Source y*
**sw** - *Source width*
**sh** - *Source height*
**dx** - *Destination x*
**dy** - *Destination y*
**dw** - *Destination width*
**dh** - *Destination height*

Answer (score -1):

Create a new canvas, and copy the selected portion to that new canvas, and then get the toDataURL() from that new canvas.

Comment: how can I copy that selected portion to the new canvas?

Comment: This does not explain *how* any of that is achieved.